# Spring Boot 2 - Unsatisfied dependency on Feign client when autowired for service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I have a pretty simple situation and I've tried a few things now and I can't find the cause of this issue. It claims it can not Autowire the Feign client class though this is how I have done this in Spring Boot 1.5.9. At least I'm pretty sure. Things work fine in all my unit tests though I'm mocking this client. Formerly it was a part of an imported library however to eliminate possibilities of me not properly locating the bean I just added it to the same project.

I'm not the most experienced with Spring or Feign so I'm wondering if it's obvious what I'm missing here.

Simple feign client:

```
@FeignClient(name = "my-other-service")
public interface OtherServiceClient {

    @GetMapping(value = "/foo/{fooId}")
    @ResponseBody
    String getFoo(@PathVariable int fooId);
}
```

Main application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
// Had a component scan here when in other module
public class MyServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The service that depends on the feign client:

```
@Service
public class FooService {
    private final FooRepository fooRepository;
    private final BarRepository barRepository;
    private OtherServiceClient otherServiceClient;

    @Autowired
    public OrderService(
            FooRepository fooRepository,
            BarRepository barRepository,
            OtherServiceClient otherServiceClient) {
        this.fooRepository= fooRepository;
        this.barRepository = barRepository;
        this.otherServiceClient = otherServiceClient;
    }
```

Since it might be an auto config thing here is the configuration report:

```
============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration#configServicePropertySource matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.config.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor' (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration#configurationPropertiesBeans matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration#configurationPropertiesRebinder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.RetryConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable' (OnClassCondition)

   DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled) did not find property 'spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.RsaEncryptionConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Keystore nor key found in Environment (EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.KeyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.VanillaEncryptionConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingClass found unwanted class 'org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor' (OnClassCondition)

   EurekaDiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled) did not find property 'spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
```

Relevant parts of the pom...I'm using Maven.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>

    <spring-restdocs.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</spring-restdocs.version>
    <snippetsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-snippets</snippetsDirectory>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Stack trace pruned from some of the less pertinent data...

```
2018-03-21 15:07:20.481  INFO 26756 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.14.Final}
2018-03-21 15:07:20.483  INFO 26756 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-03-21 15:07:20.539  INFO 26756 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
    2018-03-21 15:07:20.930  INFO 26756 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    2018-03-21 15:07:21.445  INFO 26756 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:113) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.makeLobCreatorBuilder(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:54) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:271) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at ...
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        .
        .
        .
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at com.myservice.EqOrderServiceApplication.main(EqOrderServiceApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.createClob()Ljava/sql/Clob;
        ... 49 common frames omitted

    2018-03-21 15:07:22.361  INFO 26756 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2018-03-21 15:07:23.295  INFO 26756 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing FeignContext-dbe-order-detail: startup date [Wed Mar 21 15:07:23 EDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@1290d90c
    2018-03-21 15:07:23.316  INFO 26756 --- [  restartedMain] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
    2018-03-21 15:07:24.048  WARN 26756 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController' defined in file [<my path>\controller\MainController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'orderService' defined in file [<my path>\service\OrderService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.myservice.OtherServiceClient ': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: PathVariable annotation was empty on param 0.
    2018-03-21 15:07:24.049  INFO 26756 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing FeignContext-dbe-order-detail: startup date [Wed Mar 21 15:07:23 EDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@1290d90c
    2018-03-21 15:07:24.051  INFO 26756 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2018-03-21 15:07:24.053  WARN 26756 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method 'close' failed on bean with name 'eurekaRegistration': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    2018-03-21 15:07:24.055  INFO 26756 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2018-03-21 15:07:24.077  INFO 26756 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2018-03-21 15:07:24.091 ERROR 26756 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController' defined in file [<my path>\controller\MainController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'orderService' defined in file [<my path>\service\OrderService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.myservice.OtherServiceClient ': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: PathVariable annotation was empty on param 0.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        .
        .
        .
        at com.myservice.MyServiceApplication.main(MyServiceApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'orderService' defined in file [<my path>\service\OrderService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.myservice.OtherServiceClient ': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: PathVariable annotation was empty on param 0.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        .
        .
        .
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.myservice.OtherServiceClient ': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: PathVariable annotation was empty on param 0.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1645) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1178) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:258) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1291) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PathVariable annotation was empty on param 0.
        at feign.Util.checkState(Util.java:128) ~[feign-core-9.5.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.annotation.PathVariableParameterProcessor.processArgument(PathVariableParameterProcessor.java:51) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.0.0.BUILD-20180321.114528-231.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringMvcContract.processAnnotationsOnParameter(SpringMvcContract.java:238) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.0.0.BUILD-20180321.114528-231.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(Contract.java:110) ~[feign-core-9.5.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringMvcContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(SpringMvcContract.java:133) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.0.0.BUILD-20180321.114528-231.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidatateMetadata(Contract.java:66) ~[feign-core-9.5.1.jar:na]
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$ParseHandlersByName.apply(ReflectiveFeign.java:146) ~[feign-core-9.5.1.jar:na]
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign.newInstance(ReflectiveFeign.java:53) ~[feign-core-9.5.1.jar:na]
        at feign.Feign$Builder.target(Feign.java:218) ~[feign-core-9.5.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.HystrixTargeter.target(HystrixTargeter.java:39) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.0.0.BUILD-20180321.114528-231.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.loadBalance(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:223) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.0.0.BUILD-20180321.114528-231.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getObject(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:244) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.0.0.BUILD-20180321.114528-231.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:161) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 50 common frames omitted

    Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50881', transport: 'socket'

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm pretty stumped at this point.

EDIT:

Update, so, in order to investigate more as I was confident the service started prior to beginning the Feign work I commented out all references to the feign client and the feign client itself except the the configuration annotations on the application class. I still see the reference to the database driver on start up but the application does indeed run. This is the exception I see on start up but without Feign interactions the application starts.

```
2018-03-21 17:04:56.222  INFO 27424 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.createClob()Ljava/sql/Clob;
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

The database driver is on the older side so I might see about updating it to the ojdbc8 driver maybe while I'm at it...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you using rest feign client service we need to define exact @Pathvariable name.

```
@GetMapping("/hello-world/from/{from}/to/{to}")
 public String getHelloWorld(@PathVariable("from") String from, @PathVariable ("to") String to);
```

Comment: I don't understand this - it seems to be randomly required. For example this was fine: `@PostMapping("/v2/customers/{customerId}/cards" CustomerAddCardResponse customerAddCard(URI host, @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token, @PathVariable String customerId, CustomerAddCardRequest request);`
But this was not `@GetMapping("/v2/merchants/{merchantId}") MerchantResponse getMerchant(URI host, @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token, @PathVariable String merchantId);`

Answer (score 20):

There was an issue in feign client before. I guess you are experiencing the same maybe because you are using an old version but what you should do is including the pathVariable name in your @PathVariable annotation like this 
    `@RequestMapping(value = "/hello/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String hello(@PathVariable(value = "name") String name);`

You can find the details from [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/861)

Comment: If this is an answer, could you elaborate it a bit more? If not, you should have posted it as a comment.

Comment: I guess I totally missed the second exception. I though the first error is causing the context shutdown. But after I dig more I saw that you might have this issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1588

Comment: Can you try with adding pathVariable name like this @PathVariable(value = "fooId")

Comment: Is there a way to get better information from the driver error? The application ran otherwise as is until I began adding the feign client code to interact with another application.

Comment: Additionally confusing about that is that it sounds like I am using a lob or clob but my schema for the included objects have no column of that type.

Comment: I guess it is not about what you use but about the version incompatibility between different jars. I found a similar topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066570/why-do-i-keep-getting-the-java-lang-abstractmethoderror-oracle-jdbc-driver-ora

Comment: Added an update. Commented out the feign code and it runs but I do still see that database driver error. The rest of our codebase does use that driver for the same database. Might try to update to the ojdbc8 driver for the sake of it but not sure why it will matter. Thanks for the link, I'll look.

Comment: Have you also tried using pathVariable name like this @PathVariable(value = "fooId") with Feign. I know there was an issue about this before.

Comment: Dude, not sure why...but the application at least ran when I changed the @PathVariable syntax. I don't know if it works works but it at least runs which was my primary concern at the moment. If you make an answer of that I'll have to accept it.

Comment: Worked fine for me, I was using @PathVariable String id, replaced it with @PathVariable("id") String id. It worked perfectly fine afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot, when using @PathVariable, it's not necessary to explicitly specify the parameter name if you are using the default parameter name, which is derived from the method parameter name.

For example, instead of:

```
@GetMapping("/example/{customerId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> exampleMethod(@PathVariable(value="customerId") BigInteger customerId)
```

You can simply use:

```
@GetMapping("/example/{customerId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> exampleMethod(@PathVariable BigInteger customerId)
```

This works well in most cases, and Spring Boot is able to match the path variable correctly.

However, if you are facing issues with the Maven Compiler Plugin, particularly version 3.5.1, I recommend updating the plugin to a newer version. In my case, upgrading from version 3.5.1 to 3.8.1 resolved the issue.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version> 
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It's worth mentioning that this solution is tested with Spring Boot version 2.7.7 and Spring Cloud version 2021.0.8. Ensure compatibility with your specific versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with @pathvariable, its resolved when I added the value property of `@PathVariable` like below,

```
@PathVariable(value = "from") String from,
            @PathVariable(value = "to") String to);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Even though there seems to be a problem in the spring-cloud-oepnfiegn](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/863), most of the time the reason is not the framework, based on my experience.

The problem often comes out from something like this: you use some library, that contains the OpenFeign clients to the services. In this case, the issue is often in the compilation of this client library. [See the related thread in spring-cloud-oepnfiegn bugtracker](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/178).

The issue is that `javac`, by default, does not retain parameter's names of the methods and constructors in the bytecode. Therefore, if the authors of the client lib relied on the spring to resolve `@PathVariable` by simple parameter name - that just does not work - all information has been erased already.

So to solve this problem, you need to either:

- Add an explicit `@PathVariable("someVar")` mapping to the path variable in the client lib, then recompile
- Or you need to recompile the client with `-parameters` flag. [This flag will include metadata about parameter's names into the bytecode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCJABJA) and spring will resolve the mapping without any additional hints.

Unfortunately, I do not know the ways to fix it unless you do not have access to the library source code. Hope it helped.

Answer (score -1):

```
@GetMapping(value = "/foo/{fooId}")
    @ResponseBody
    String getFoo(@PathVariable(value="fooId") int fooId);
```

will do