# AbstractMethodError inTomcat 8

Tags: database, jdbc, tomcat8, jtds, context.xml

I am getting this error.

> Stacktrace:] with root cause 
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 | java.lang.AbstractMethodError
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.isValid(JtdsConnection.java:2833)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:874)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:270)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:389)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2398)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2381)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2110)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.jsp.startpage_jsp.getDBConnection(startpage_jsp.java:60)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.jsp.startpage_jsp.getUserInfo(startpage_jsp.java:474)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.jsp.startpage_jsp._jspService(startpage_jsp.java:732)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at nl.planon.tomcat.ForgotPasswordFilter.doFilter(ForgotPasswordFilter.java:78)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at nl.planon.webrequestsigner.WebRequestSignerFilter.doFilter(WebRequestSignerFilter.java:67)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:240)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at nl.planon.owasp.valve.WhitelistHTTPMethodsValve.invoke(WhitelistHTTPMethodsValve.java:72)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at nl.planon.owasp.valve.XSSProtectionHeaderValve.invoke(XSSProtectionHeaderValve.java:175)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at nl.planon.tomcat.AddHeaderValve.invoke(AddHeaderValve.java:117)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at nl.planon.tomcat.ClickjackHostValve.invoke(ClickjackHostValve.java:107)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/06/06 08:49:59 |

I found some solutions with adding **validationQuery="select 1"** to context.xml. But in my context.xml I don't have a resource.

```
<Context>
<!-- Authenticate against PlanonRealmLogin (JAAS) -->
<!--   allRolesMode=authOnly" means that no role is needed for '*' requirement -->
<Realm appName="PlanonRealmLogin" 
    className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm"
    userClassNames="nl.planon.cerebeus.PnUser" 
    roleClassNames="nl.planon.cerebeus.PnRole"
    allRolesMode="authOnly"/>

<!--Valve className="nl.planon.tomcat.AccessKeyValve" throttle="5000"/-->

<!--Valve className="nl.planon.tomcat.ForgotPasswordLoginValve"/-->

<!-- Will force authentication attempts to be parsed as UTF-8. The Landingpage will prevent HTTP 408 messages
    because now, even without a stored original location, Tomcat knows where to forward to. -->
    <!-- exceptionAttributeName="PnLoginException"--> 
<Valve className="nl.planon.tomcat.PnMessageFormAuthenticator" landingPage="/" characterEncoding="utf-8"/>

<!-- This valve excludes valid webdav users with role webdav_readwrite to enter the web application(s) -->
<!--Valve className="nl.planon.tomcat.ExcludingRoleValve"/-->

<!--Parameter name="trustedServiceKeystore" value="${catalina.home}/webclientKeystore.jks" />
<Parameter name="trustedServiceName" value="webclient" /-->

<Manager pathname="" />

     <ResourceLink
      name="jdbc/PlanonDS"
      global="jdbc/PlanonDS"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<!-- Whitelist the minimal set of HTTP Methods that Web Bootstrap needs -->
<!--Valve className="nl.planon.owasp.valve.WhitelistHTTPMethodsValve" methods="GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE" /-->
```

In my server.xml I have mentioned resource.

```
  <GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>

<Resource name="jdbc/PlanonDS"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  username=""
  password=""
  driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SZH1DB;instance=planon"
  validationQuery="select 1"
  maxActive="8"
  maxIdle="4"/>
```

Here I have used **validationQuery="select 1"**. But still I get the same error.

Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: Related, semi-duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194990/why-do-i-get-java-lang-abstractmethoderror-when-trying-to-load-a-blob-in-the-db

Comment: Consider switching to the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver. The jTDS driver only implements JDBC 3 (Java 1.4) and the method being called was introduced in JDBC 4 (Java 6).

Comment: Thank you @MarkRotteveel.I didnt get what you mean by jtds not supported. I dodnt understand what should I do.

Comment: I never said "jtds not supported". I just say that jTDS doesn't implement recent versions of JDBC (the latest version is 4.3, with Java 9 or higher), so you might be better off using the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver instead.

Comment: Yeah, Okay. Thank you very much.